# upload data from on-premises folder to Azure DB as the server admin is SQL authenticated user

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure

I have azure SQL DB, with SQL authenticated user as server admin, we have a requirement to upload data from on-premises folder to Azure DB. How can we achieve this?
1.SQL authenticated user is not recognized in AD
2.is there any **service account** other than this server admin to az-sql-dbs?

Comment: Check with your system admin team and check if your AD is in sync with Azure?  If yes you can add your windows account as a login in logical server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure SSIS integration with Azure Data Factory as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-lift-shift-ssis-packages-overview). On [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-connect-with-windows-auth) resource you will find how to run packages that use Windows Authentication to connect to on-premises resources like a folder.

Hope this helps.